# Autowired or new RetryTemplate

Tags: java, spring

In one of my classes, I want to use a spring class `RetryTemplate` with specific parameters in `SimpleRetryPolicy` and `FixedBackOffPolicy`. `RetryTemplate` is not a bean and I think about two options:

1. In my class, create it, as in old fashioned, with new () without any Autowired.
2. Create it in a config file as a Bean and make Autowired.

And even more generic question is: should I create an object as a Bean in a config file also when it is created only for the use of a specific class with specific parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Just use new() the old fashion way. If you don't share the instances between different classes and this class of yours is not "service" or something like that then there is no point in injecting it through spring.

Another (big) difference is that if you make it a bean spring by default makes it singleton and injects that same instance into the different components that need it. If that's not the required behavior then you don't need to use that mechanism. We are still coding in java so there is nothing wrong in just creating the object you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would use it as the bean. Why? Because its easier to test your service then, you can mock this `RetryTemplate` bean if needed, or even, if you are using tests with context you can define test bean, which will substitute your real one just for testing.

Its the same approach you have with the `RestTemplate` and `TestRestTemplate` in spring-boot, when you are running tests spring would automatically create bean `TestRestTemplate` which is an implementation of `RestTemplate` extending it and preconfigured so its easier to test your client services.

Using just `new` it would be hard to mock it, in case its needed.

Or may be in future you will want to add another `RetryStrategy` and switch between them using profiles, depending on environment you are running your application.

Also it doesn't seem that you want to create new copy of `RetryStrategy` for each service which would be using it, bean by default is singleton, meaning that it would use the same instance(however it can be altered to create new instance for each service, it is autowired, if you need it).

Overall using beans over creating entities inside yuor service is more flexible for future extension and testing.